# Heroku- running rails app not sending mail and not showing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, actionmailer

I have a Rails app 
and in that i have a form which sends the mail after submitting

the production settings are

**production.rb**

```
  config.eager_load = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'jobzgoform.herokuapp.com'}
  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # SMTP settings for gmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => "gmail.com",
      :user_name            => 'mygmailid',
      :password             => 'mygmailpassword',
      :authentication       => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

**form_mailer.rb**

```
class FormMailer < ApplicationMailer
 def registration_mail(form)
  mail(to: form.email, subject: 'JobzGo Registration')
 end
end
```

**forms_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @form = Form.create(form_params)
    if @form.save
      FormMailer.registration_mail(@form).deliver
      redirect_to forms_path
    end
  end
```

running on heroku it shows error after submitting the form i am receiving the data in the database but then it generated error on the page and mail is not sent. and in the logs i get

```
2015-11-27T13:19:43.550779+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/forms" host=jobzgoform.herokuapp.com request_id=9943fd5e-a5f9-40cf-8f85-b6fd4cee59f0 fwd="182.71.29.59" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=685ms status=500 bytes=1683
2015-11-27T13:19:43.852960+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jobzgoform.herokuapp.com request_id=6b6d904b-7c0e-4cc1-8219-a6cc3bd77d31 fwd="182.71.29.59" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=157
```

not able to debug as i am not getting any error

Please help!!

Comment: Have you added `rails_12factor` gem in your Gemfile for production ?

Comment: no , its needed to send mail ?

Comment: Its good for debugging. You add it for production, run your code again, and see the logs and update here. There is good chance you would be able to figure out the issue by yourself.

Comment: 2015-11-27T13:49:31.739089+00:00 app[web.1]: Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
2015-11-27T13:49:31.739090+00:00 app[web.1]: ):

Comment: but i have given the correct gmail id and password

Comment: Could you try with same smtp settings on both `development.rb` and `production.rb` ?

Comment: yes on development i am receiving the mail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96362/discussion-between-dusht-and-user4965201).

Answer (score 1):

Please add `rails_12factor` gem (It helps in debugging/better_error_visibility on Heroku) in your Gemfile for production.

See the Heroku logs. Probability is you would be able to figure out the solution by yourself.

Also you can run `rails server -e production` to run in production environment at your local.

Hope it helps!